KMM Build only for Android
I have a kmm application and I want to speed up the build time on the CI side
CI works on Mac
I would like to run a build only for Android
Using the command
./gradlew build 

or
./gradlew assemble

All targets start to be assembled, I would like to avoid this
Expecting:
./gradlew build (or else)

run only for android target

Well, the simple answer:
./gradlew assembleDebug

or
./gradlew assembleRelease

I'm not sure why these aren't listed when running ./gradlew tasks, but they've been around in the Android Gradle plugin forever. If you have a different variant, say staging, you can just run:
./gradlew assembleStaging

Since this is CI, you might want testing as well, but I don't know off hand, and it depends (I think) on if you're talking about just JVM unit tests or app/instrumentation tests.
